# css center div not working

Tags: html, css

I want to center the speaker div, which is within the review div. i cannot seem to get it working. :(

HTML:

```
<div class="review">
<div class="speaker">
<p>SPEAKER DIV</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.speaker{
align:center;
}
```

This doesn't work :/

Answer (score 9):

Give it a width and margin:0 auto;

```
<div class="review">
    <div class="speaker">
        <p>SPEAKER DIV</p>
    </div>
</div>

div.speaker{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[See it in action!](http://jsfiddle.net/pgHUW/)

Answer (score 8):

There’s no such CSS property as `align`.

When you say you want to “center” the speaker div, what exactly do you mean?

You can center-align *its text* like this:

```
.speaker {
    text-align:center;
}
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/X7LN5/)

If, alternatively, you want the speaker div to only be as wide as its text, and be positioned in the center of the review div, then you’d need to use this:

```
.review {
    text-align:center;
}

.speaker {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/wxha4/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm about a year late to the party, but here goes:

In most browsers, this will work:

```
.speaker{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, in IE8 and below, the `margin:auto` will not work (IE8 only if there is no !DOCTYPE declaration. [See W3Schools Horizontal-Align Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp))

In that case, you can use a combination of `text-align: center` and `width` to get the desired effect:

```
.review{
    text-align:center;
}
.speaker{
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The downside to this method is that you have to declare a width, or it won't be centered.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It work perfectly.

```
.speaker{ 
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
```

}

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent a text-align: center;
Then you can move the child anywhere in the parent div

```
.speaker {
       margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.speaker p{
text-align:center;
}
```

or

```
.speaker {
 text-align:center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because that syntax does not exist. You need to center the div via the `margin` attribute.

```
.speaker{
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/t4kBj/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `align` attribute in CSS. Set the horizontal margins to auto to centre a block. See [Centring using CSS](http://dorward.me.uk/www/centre/#block) for more details (including work arounds for Internet Explorer issues)