# issue with horizontal-central aligment of the contents of </p:panel>

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

In my JSF-PrimeFaces webapp I am having  and I need to horizontal-align its contents to center. How can I do that?

Here is the code for the:

```
    <p:panel id="businesses_panel" header="#{business.businessName}" styleClass="mini-panel panel-grid tr panel-grid td panel-hover panel-header-title-small">
<div align="center">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
        <h:graphicImage alt="#{business.businessName}" value="#{business.logoFullPath}" class="small-panel-image" />
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</div>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align="center"` is deprecated. You should instead use css, you try:

```
            <style type="text/css">
                .test table{
                    margin-left: auto !important;
                    margin-right: auto !important;
                }
            </style>
            <p:panel styleClass="test">
                   ...
            </p:panel>
```

**See also:**

- [css center div not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661782/css-center-div-not-working)
- [CENTERING THINGS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center)

Comment: I have tested, and it work fine, so you should debug clientside to get error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #businesses_panel .ui-panel-content {
        margin-left:  auto !important;
        margin-right: auto !important;
    }
</style>
```